# How can I reproduce this simple tree diagram?

Tags: diagrams, trees, forest, qtree

I would like to create this simple tree diagram in LYX. I tried using forest but I did not figure out how to add text to the different levels and display percentages.

[image]

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far...

Comment: Welcome! If you post the code for a small document using Forest (or something else), somebody can help you with adding the labels etc.

Answer (score 9):

Please always include the code you've got as it makes it much easier to help effectively. Not knowing how you tried to do things or what you have done makes it really hard to provide meaningful explanation.

The percentages, for example, are just done in the usual way i.e. with `\%`. The labels can be created with `label`.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [, circle, fill, inner sep=1pt
    [80\%, label=left:Data Gathering
      [70\%, label=left:Data Analysis]
      [30\%]
    ]
    [20\%
      [90\%]
      [10\%]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: tree]

Comment: Great. Thank you so much. I will post the code next time.

Comment: @RoxanneJ.Kovacs Sounds good to me ;).